# ffmpeg - extract clip without reading the entire file

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using the following command to extract a 30 second clip from a remote file:

```
ffmpeg -i "\\some_remote_server\c$\Recordings\input.ts" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 300 -to 330 "C:\Clips\output.ts"
```

The input file is large (gigabytes). It appears ffmpeg reads the entire file over the network in order to extract just 30 seconds.

Is there a way to stop ffmpeg reading the entire file?

Comment: Which protocol for the input? Is it seekable?

Comment: What is the communication protocol for the input? You appear to be on Windows, so I suppose it's SMB. I'll check on this.

Comment: Thanks Gyan, yes it's just a normal SMB share